# How to test if Api returns a specific message after the exception is caught in the try/catch

Tags: c#

I am writing a test method in xunit. So when a user fails to enroll, a specific message is returned in the catch block. In the test method, I want to check if the right message is returned. But when I run, I get this message instead:

```
EnrollUser failed with HTTP response code:BadRequest.
```

If anyone can help me find out, if it possible, how to retrieve the message I want.
Below is the code.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EnrollUser([FromUri]int id, int userId, int? 
    organizationId = null)
{               
    try
    {                   
        if (organizationId.HasValue)
        {
            Do something.....
        }
        else
        {
            Do something.....
        }

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var errorMsg = $"User enrollment failed for userId:{userId}, serviceId:{id}.";                  
        return (IHttpActionResult)BadRequest(errorMsg);
    }
}

[Fact]
public async Task EnrollUser_Should_Return_Failure_Message()
{   
    const int userId = 2310;
    const int serviceId = 9;

    const string expectedMessage = "User enrollment failed for userId:{userId}, serviceId:{id}.";     


    Func<Task> act = () => EnrollUser(userId, serviceId);

    var actualException = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(act);

    Assert.Equal(expectedMessage, actualException.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is handled in the `EnrollUser` method so this method will never throw an exception, It will return BadRequest object instead that you can use to compare the message.

```
var result = await act;
Assert.Equal(expectedMessage, act.Request);
```